# GUI result output to user

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, output

The display message is not displaying as a GUI. Currently I have the output message set up as a system out print ln but I need a string output to display a message that states if the lists are identical or not. How can I make this change? I am using the following List 1=5 2 5 6 1 6 and list 2=5 2 5 6 1 6 Here is the updated code:

```
// Enter values for list1
  String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter list1: ");
int size1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
int[] list1 = new int[size1];

for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) 
  list1[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);

// Enter values for list2
String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter list2: ");
int size2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);
int[] list2 = new int[size2];

for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) 
  list2[i] = Integer.parseInt(input2);

if (equals(list1, list2)) {
  System.out.println("Two lists are strictly identical");
}
else {
  System.out.println("Two lists are not strictly identical");
}
```

}

```
public static boolean equals(int[] list1, int[] list2) {
if (list1.length != list2.length)
  return false;

for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) 
  if (list1[i] != list2[i])
    return false;

return true;
```

}

}

Comment: You might want to start by looking at swing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: This is much too broad to answer here - you need to go and read about Java GUIs libraries (probably Swing) and try some tutorials - then ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: There is also [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm).

Answer (score 0):

if you wan't it your text to display on a frame rather than a console you can use JLabels & for your input use JTextFields ... also take a look [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)